# Handling Azure SSO bypass authentication on Selenium

Tags: selenium, azure-active-directory

Hope you're doing fine.

So I have this application which is stored on Azure and it uses Azure AD for authenticating users.

**It has an login button which redirects the user to microsoft.login.**

Automating the login to execute the rest of the tests through the UI does not work well because of the many redirects microsoft login goes around.
So I was trying to execute it as sending a post request but it seems like no user and password are needed to execute the requests.
On the body I am sending the following information:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

```
{
  clientId
  clientSecret
  scope
  grantType
}
```

The response returns the following params:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": 'tokenCodeGeneratedByTheResponse'
}
```

After setting the access token on the webdriver browser cookie and clicking on the application login page, it redirects to the microsoft.login page, making the access_token useless.

I've read microsoft documentation and it doesn't show any api which sends username and password to get the access_token, making me quite confused about it.

Does anyone have any idea of what is going on?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the resource owner password credentials flow in [AAD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc) however it is not recommended for production.

This flow can let you obtain the token without UI

- Native client
- Public client flow
- Add new claims

On-behalf-of-flow is not supported in AAD B2C [currently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-apps#current-limitations). Alternatively, you could create your private [agent](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fpipelines%2Fagents%2Fv2-windows%3Fview%3Dazure-devops%26viewFallbackFrom%3Dvsts&data=04%7C01%7Cv-lileu%40microsoft.com%7C9f010a52c678414e5f9408d8e940036f%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637515808436900668%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=UeJyoL1ZX2rKp1fjO5dO6sYnPfypWFPqhSwvcWAfmjs%3D&reserved=0). To test your test make sure to run your self-hosted agent in an interactive [mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#visible-ui-mode).